# ErrorDocument redirect to different page per virtual directory

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, http-status-code-404, errordocument

I've tried to look this up every way I could and couldn't find a direct answer to this particular question. I have some .htaccess rewrite rules for some friendly URLs and want to handle 404 errors that may occur in various ways.

First, here are a couple of the rewrite rules:

```
RewriteRule ^newsite/designer/([A-Za-z0-9_.%&-]+).html/?$ newsite/catalog.php?m=$1 [NC,L,B,QSA]
RewriteRule ^newsite/search/([A-Za-z0-9_.%'&-]+)/?$ newsite/catalog.php?kw=$1 [NC,L,B,QSA]
```

I would like to direct 404 errors for search/ differently than 404 error within designer/. Each having their own destination. But since these are not actual directories I can't just put a separate .htaccess file in the directoies.

Ultimately I want to have all other 404 not expressly redirected to go to the catchall, like

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

Is this possible and how?

Comment: So you want `/newsite/designer/blablabla` to goto `/newsite/designer-404.php` and similarly `/newsite/search/blablabla` to  `/newsite/search-404.php` ?

Comment: Not exactly. Only if the result of /newsite/designer/blablabla yields a 404 error do I want it to go to the custom error page

Comment: Yes that is what I meant by using `/blablabla` (which doesn't exist usually)

Comment: Then yes. The main thing is that if a link doesn't match the rewrite rule is when I get the 404. Else it passes as a variable to my script which handles it from there. This is most likely only going to happen at /search/ Just trying to have a catch in place if a link slips through unmatched.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use `<Location>` sections in your configuration:

```
<Location /newsite/designer>
    ErrorDocument 404 wherever
</Location>
```

However, there are probably many cases in which you may not get a 404 (if the request matches the `RewriteRule`s and it's inside the script that you can't find a match), depending on how your script works.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware of <Location>. If I added in sequence 3 <location> statements and then ended with one without, will the last one be default if it doesn't match location, or would it override the locations?

Comment: I tried <location> and it yielded a 500 server error for the whole site. I tried your version (replacing "whatever") and then tried some versions I found on the apache site. I guess my server doesn't like <location>

Comment: Did you put the <Location> within a <VirtualHost> section? I just tried it on a server of mine and it works exactly as expected. What shows up in the logs when you add that code? What version of Apache are you using?

Comment: No, I didn't have it in a <VirtualHost> section. Is there anything else that needs to wrap around it? This is the first time I've seen these commands.

Comment: Not that I know of. In my Apache config, I have a dedicated config file for each virtual host, and simply adding the 3 lines above within the existing <VirtualHost ...> section for the specific virtual host makes it work. That's of course if you use virtual hosts. You can test the validity of your Apache configuration without restarting it with `apachectl configtest`. And don't forget to check out your logs to know exactly what went wrong!

Answer (score 0):

You can use these rewrite rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

# specific 404 handlers
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^newsite/search/ /newsite/404.php?base=search [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^newsite/designer/ /newsite/404.php?base=designer [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^newsite/designer/([A-Za-z0-9_.%&-]+).html/?$ newsite/catalog.php?m=$1 [NC,L,B,QSA]
RewriteRule ^newsite/search/([A-Za-z0-9_.%'&-]+)/?$ newsite/catalog.php?kw=$1 [NC,L,B,QSA]

# generic 404 handling:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^newsite/designer/ /newsite/404.php [L,NC]
```